# Copy Worksheet if Exist and Create new file if not

Tags: excel, vba, macos

hi can you help figure out how to copy worksheet if it existing, and if it is not will automatically create a new workbook then save as blank. please see my code below I try it in if the file is existing copy the file and if not create a new blank file.

```
Workbooks.Open path1
Sheets.Select

If Sheets("Draft") = "" Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveFolder & "\D201\D201.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Else
    Sheets("Draft").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveFolder & "\D201\D201.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    Workbooks(file1).Close
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If
```

and I've encountered an error it says **Subscript out of range**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you didn't try real hard there (given debugging the error thrown would have lead you to the obvious error). 
Here are two possible ways to test for the existence of sheet with a specific name:

```
Sub Temp()

''' Two possible ways to determine if a sheet with a specific name exists
''' Both assume you're looking for the sheet in the Active Book
''' There are other ways
    
''' Sledge hammer approach (very efficient)
    Dim lgErr&
    On Error Resume Next: Err.Clear
        With Sheets("Draft"): End With: lgErr = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    If lgErr <> 0 Then
        ' Sheets("Draft") does not exist in the active workbook
    Else
        ' Sheets("Draft") does exist in the active workbook
    End If

''' More subtle approach (just as effective and only marginally less efficient)
    Dim in1%
    For in1 = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(in1).Name = "Draft" Then Exit For
    Next in1
    If in1 > Sheets.Count Then
        ' Sheets("Draft") does not exist in the active workbook
    Else
        ' Sheets("Draft") does exist in the active workbook
    End If

End Sub
```

Notes:
The 1st approach if often used by people confident of their vba skills.
The risk is that a coding error between On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo 0 could result in and invalid conclusion.
The 2nd approach does not have this same risk.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I guess my effort of trying is not yet enough :D but thanks I'll study more to understand this language well :D

Answer (score 0):

i usually use a function to test if a sheet exists in my workbook:

```
Function Feuille_Existe(ByVal Nom_Feuille As String) As Boolean

Dim Feuille As Excel.Worksheet
  On Error GoTo Feuille_Absente_Error
    Set Feuille = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Nom_Feuille)
  On Error GoTo 0
  Feuille_Existe = True
Exit Function

Feuille_Absente_Error:
  Feuille_Existe = False
End Function
```

Put this on top of your module and when you need it in your code :

```
If Feuille_Existe("XXX") Then
    'do what you want'
End If
```